# .then do not work after call service function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i have this simple service

```
angular.module('tadeluApp')
  .service('fileUpload', ['$http', function ($http) {

    this.uploadFileToUrl = function(file, uploadUrl){
       var fd = new FormData();
       fd.append('file', file);

       $http.post(uploadUrl, fd, {
          transformRequest: angular.identity,
          headers: {'Content-Type': undefined}
       })

       .success(function(data){

          return data.url;

       })

       .error(function(){
       });
    }
 }]);
```

It's just to upload an image to server, now in the controller i call the service and the function 'uploadFileToUrl'.

```
self.uploadFile = function(){
   var file = self.myFile;

   // console.log('file is ' );
   // console.dir(file);

   var uploadUrl = "http://111.11.11.11/api/upload/";

   fileUpload.uploadFileToUrl(file, uploadUrl).then(function(data) {

    console.log('test data ->', data);

   });

   console.log(dataInfo.image);

};
```

[---> server response <---](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Qs59.jpg)

The problem is, i need to receive the response of this post in my controller, i try to use a .then function after call the service function in my controller, but it did not work. some help? thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to return the Promise being generated and return by `$http` so the Promise chain is continued. The code provided doesn't actually return the Promise when calling `uploadFileToUrl()`.

```
this.uploadFileToUrl = function(file, uploadUrl){  
   var fd = new FormData();
   fd.append('file', file);

   return $http.post(uploadUrl, fd, {
      transformRequest: angular.identity,
      headers: {'Content-Type': undefined}
   })
    .then(function(data) {
      return data.url;
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
      // Handle error
    });
}
```